# "Кроткий": родственно ли слову "короткий"?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Если родственно, то с какой стати? Кроткий — мягкий, тот, кто подставляет вторую щеку. Что у него короткое?

Comment: Вкратце - кроткий - это тот, у кого характер "короткий". А вообще соглашусь с @Марк Из

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Что у него короткое?

Фаллос. Кроткий - это буквально укрощёный кастрированием. Кастрированное животное становится ленивым, вялым, спокойным. Из характера такого животного исчезает агрессивность и игривость. Отсюда видимо и перенос.

Слово кроткий произошло от krotiti (укрощать, усмирять) < (кастрировать), в диалектах и др. слав. яз. еще известного.

Comment: отсюда вывод: женщины кроткими быть не могут ;-))

Comment: @Docent, или наоборот, они кроткие от рождения.

Comment: Ну-ну, надейтесь ... ;-))

Answer (score 2):

А ничего, что кастрация если и предполагает отсечение, то совсем другого?
Что-то отдает эта версия какой-то народно-спиндажной этимологией...

Кстати, "фалос" тоже не смотрится в подобном контексте.

//------------ 
Короче, при беглом просмотре не обнаружил ничего убедительного насчет кастрации.
Но даже сведение кротости к глаголу "кротить" (по Фасмеру он вторичен по отношению к прилагательному) не даёт оснований принять этимологическое родство кротости и краткости ("короткости").